# Adding storyboard navigation to computer vision sample code

Tags: swift, computer-vision, uikit, storyboard, object-detection

Here are my first steps toward iOS and Swift, please be kind :)

My goal is to build a demo app based on the sample code for recognizing objects in live capture: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture

The app launches into the live inference showing inference results on top of live camera feed. I'd like to build some views around the existing inferece view controller to showcase an app that has some basic UI for a use case with a button to start the inference view controller intead of launching directly into it.

As of now, I don't fully understand the ViewController architecture and I'm also new to Swift. I figured out how to navigate with storyboards non-programatically which would be sufficient for a showcase app. At the moment I haven't figured out how to override the launch process into the first view controller of the storyboard and instantiate the object detection view controller from here.

I've tried to create a simple storyboard and created a start view. From this start view I've linked a button with an action segue to the main ViewController.swift or the VisionObjectRecognitionViewController.swift, both not working as expected.